# Where can I find nsis error codes?

Tags: nsis, error-code

I'm building an nsis script and sometimes I print the error codes, but then I cant find anything on the web that maps my error id to a proper description on whats the error.

There isn't any error code listage for NSIS?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about process exit codes or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If we take the example you posted on the NSIS forum: `ExecWait "net start Apache 2.2" $0` then $0 will contain the exit code of the net.exe process and you cannot really know for sure what they mean other than that 0 usually means success. Some applications use the Win32 error codes and you can look them up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Net.exe is documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490713.aspx).

If you want to control a service then [there are better ways](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_do_I_start/stop/create/remove/check_a_service) of doing that in NSIS...